# Azure Sku and offer codes for ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 LTS for ARM

Tags: azure, ubuntu

I'm hoping someone has these on-hand so I don't have to wrestle with yet another endpoint in the the azure api.

I'm looking for the Azure offer code and the sku for Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 for ARM.

I know that, for x86, the offer code for 22.04 LTS is '0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy' and the sku is '22_04-lts'.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about and have the info handy?

Thanks!
PS: If you have the x86 'v2' offer and sku that would be great too.  Not sure what the difference is from 'v1' but I see in the Azure Portal that there is a 'v1' and 'v2' option for the Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 OSes.

Comment: Actually, found part of the answer here:  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/find-ubuntu-images-on-azure

Comment: There is this command to simplify things and give you what you are looking for
<az vm image list --[output](https://i.imgur.com/vioT15f.png) table>, now suppose you want to find something specific you can edit the command as per requirement, example <az vm image list --architecture Arm64 --publisher Canonical --all --output table>
Use this document to find your particular offer code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/cli-ps-findimage

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question here:

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/find-ubuntu-images-on-azure

The URN column there includes both the offer code and the sku.  The sku is the portion after the colon.

Looks like arko posted a more generized way to answer the question.   I'll try that out next time I'm stuck on a similar issue.

Comment: I was actually waiting for you to acknowledge my comment. Anyhow from CLI you can achieve the same.

    az vm image list --architecture Arm64 --publisher Canonical --offer 0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal --all --output table


![output](https://i.imgur.com/7UCTcKs.png)

    az vm image list --architecture Arm64 --publisher Canonical --offer 0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy --all --output table

  

![output](https://i.imgur.com/ptl7V5Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out correct image is to check [Ubuntu on Azure](https://canonical-azure.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/azure-how-to/instances/find-ubuntu-images/):

For example for `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Jammy Jellyfish` the image is going to be something like that:

```
image:
  offer: "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy"
  publisher: "Canonical"
  sku: "22_04-lts"
  version: "latest"
```